# How to get the name (SSID) of the connected WiFi network using ADB?

Tags: android, adb

I am trying to get the connected Wifi network name through the ADB commands. The only method I could figure out was search the dumpsys for the WiFi network info and get the SSID. But this is cumbersome. Is there a more direct way?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

What about using dumping netstats info:

```
adb shell dumpsys netstats | grep -E 'iface=wlan.*networkId'
```

Comment: The script is not working. Looks like there is a typo above. I am not fluent in shell commands, not able to figure out the issue.

Comment: @RahulVig command works fine for me. It probably means that different hardware dump different information nothing that can be done there sorry.

Comment: @RahulVig: get rid of the `| cut...` part. `cut` is not a standard command provided by Android's Toolbox.

Comment: @Harvey yes that is how it worked for me. I marked Simas answer as correct as it provided me the right direction. I Should edit the answer.

Comment: @RahulVig I have edited the answer for future readers. Thanks Harvey.